# Control RF wave direction or path

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication

I have a rf module transmitting from an antenna. As you see in Figure 1, I have a radio mast that sends waves in all directions. I don't want this. My plan for controlling wave direction is Figure 2.

How do I control RF wave direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directional antennas generally use one of two priciples: Reflection or phasing.

Reflection works just like it does with optical mirrors, except that the wavelength is much much longer and therefore the construction of something that reflects may seem unintuitive.  Most of the world's really high gain* antennas are parabolic dishes, which focus the power in a relatively narrow beam.  For example, large radio telecscopes are like that.  Common rooftop UHF TV antennas also usually worked on this principle.

Phasing means multiple elements with careful spacing and being fed with a specific phase shift of the carrier between them.  If arranged properly, the multiple elements all add to a wave going one direction, but cancel each other out going other directions.

For example, consider two vertical antennas that each radiate equally in all horizontal directions.  These antennas, I'll call them A and B, are spaced 1/4 wavelength apart.  B is fed with a signal that lags A by 1/4 wavelength.  The signal radiated by A in the direction of B will be in phase with B by the time it gets there.  The signals from the two antennas will then add going in the direction from A to B.  However, the signal emitted by B in the direction of A will find A 180° out of phase, so the two signals cancel.  This is a simple system that has a gain of 3 dB in the A to B direction compared to one of the antennas by itself.

Phased arrays can contain more than just two phased emitters.  More emitters allows tighter control over the beam shape.  The Aegis radar is a good example of this technique taken much farther.  The large number of individual emitters all acting together form a narrow beam, which is narrow enough to focus on a single aircraft.  One advantage of this system is that the direction can be steered by electronics very quickly, much faster than a reflecting antenna can be mechanically re-aimed.

- "Gain" when applied to antennas doesn't mean the antenna can radiate more RF power than it receives electrically.  Ideally, antennas radiate all the electrical power they receive.  The difference is how concentrated it is in some directions.  Gain is how much a antenna can concentrate the power in its optimal direction relative to a standard emitter.  There are two references commonly used for 0 dB gain, a isotropic radiator and a dipole.  A dipole has a donut-shaped radiation pattern, so has gain along its plane relative to a isotropic radiator.  Both references are commonly used, so if it is not stated the statement is either ambiguous or it is implied by other context.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different designs for [directional antennas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_antenna), and which one is most useful to you depends on the particular RF frequency you will be operating at and how much directionality you want.  A simple [Yagi-Uda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yagi-Uda_antenna) with the generic design shown below is probably the easiest directional antenna to manufacture yourself.  This antenna uses a single driven dipole antenna with one (or possibly more) passive 'director' elements in front of it and one (or possibly more) slightly larger 'reflector' elements behind.

[image]

All of these directional antennas operate on the principle of [phased arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array) of smaller antennas.  In a phased array each antenna can be thought of as an individual dipole source.  The directionality happens because these individual dipoles [interfere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_%28wave_propagation%29) constructively in the direction of propagation and destructively in other directions.